# Maya Python: Apply Transformation Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, maya

I have been looking for thi answer but i don't seem to figure it out anywhere, so i hope i could get my answer here...

I'm in Maya Python API and i want to apply a transformation Matrix to a mesh.

This is how i made the mesh:

```
    mesh = om.MFnMesh()
    ShapeMesh = cmds.group(em=True)
    parentOwner = get_mobject( ShapeMesh )
    meshMObj = mesh.create(NumVerts, len(FaceCount), VertArray, FaceCount, FaceArray ,parentOwner)
    cmds.sets( ShapeMesh, e=True,forceElement='initialShadingGroup')
    defaultUVSetName = ''
    defaultUVSetName = mesh.currentUVSetName(-1)
    mesh.setUVs ( UArray, VArray, defaultUVSetName )
    mesh.assignUVs ( FaceCount,  FaceArray, defaultUVSetName )
```

This is how i create the TFM:

```
m = struct.unpack("<16f",f.read(64))
mm = om.MMatrix()
om.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList(m,mm)
mt = om.MTransformationMatrix(mm)
```

Basically i read 16 floats and convert them into a Transformation Matrix, however i don't know how to apply the mt matrix to my mesh...

I managed to get the Position,Rotation and Scale from this though, maybe it helps, this way:

```
    translate = mt.translation(om.MSpace.kWorld)
    rotate = mt.rotation().asEulerRotation()
    scaleUtil = om.MScriptUtil()
    scaleUtil.createFromList([0,0,0],3)
    scaleVec = scaleUtil.asDoublePtr()
    mt.getScale(scaleVec,om.MSpace.kWorld)
    scale = [om.MScriptUtil.getDoubleArrayItem(scaleVec,i) for i in range(0,3)]
```

Now my last step comes in applying this Matrix to the mesh, but i can't find a good way to do it, does someone know how to do this on maya?

Thanks in advance:
Seyren.

Comment: Meshes dont have transformations but rather their parent nodes the transforms do. Why bother doing this with api commands? I mean cmds.xform does a good job of doing this for you, and you dont need to implement undo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by applying the matrix to your mesh, but if you want to update the position of each point by transforming them with that matrix, then here you go for a given MFnMesh `mesh` and a given MMatrix `matrix`:

```
import banana.maya
banana.maya.patch()
from maya import OpenMaya

mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh.bnn_get('pCubeShape1')
matrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()

points = OpenMaya.MPointArray()
mesh.getPoints(points)
for i in range(points.length()):
    points.set(points[i] * matrix, i)

mesh.setPoints(points)
```

If you don't want to directly update the points of the mesh, then you need to apply the matrix to the transformation node by retrieving its parent transform and using the `MFnTransform::set()` method.

Note that I've used in my code snippet a set of extensions that I've wrote and that might be helpful if you're using the Maya Python API. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/christophercrouzet/banana.maya) and it also comes with a [documentation](http://bananamaya.readthedocs.org/) to give you an idea.

Comment: Now that we are here, do you know how to query the matrix from a specific vertex with the API ? I know how to get the points, and each one translation in worldspace, the same way with MMatrix i know how to query the matrix from and object, but i need to do it from each vertex, thanks in advance